# What is a good, *free* online "cross processing" program?

Tags: post-processing, technique, cross-processing

I am currently using Photoshop Elements 9 and the functions such as Lomo Effect and  Color Curves do not enable me to produce images with colour such as [this example on Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/wayden/3830730057/) and [this one](http://www.flickr.com/photos/villeda/2397992350/)

It is missing out on the function which you can adjust the individual colours, ie Red, Green, etc.

Can anyone please suggest any free online programs which has "Cross Processing" function so as to produce vintage yellowish pictures?

Maybe you can also give me a brieft description of the pros and cons of the program?

Comment: You ask for an online app, then you mention PS Elements, which is an offline app?

Comment: This question is a good example of why software recommendations questions don't work. Theoretically the question is still relevant, but half the answers don't work anymore (one of them closed *six years* ago) and it's attracting spam.

Comment: @mattdm but, it would have stood the test of time if people would have followed the tags and adjusted the answer for **how** to do x-processing (what is a x-p? What color channels to adjust? What contrast to adjust? etc. Things that can and will be done with any photo editor then and now and future).

Comment: @Hueco Yes, a different question about how to produce "vintage yellowish pictures" would probably have been better. But, you know, we have several of those already. :)

Answer (score 7):

***UPDATE***: After searching for similar answers I found a [question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6926/identifying-post-processing-technique) on how to do cross-processing. This led to an answer with a link to [instructions on how to do it in GIMP](http://www.flickr.com/photos/rowenar/4929839059/).

Aviary has a set of free image/photo editing software available as a web app. However, if you really want to do cross processing, you should invest in software that will allow you to edit the color channel curves, such as Lightroom, Aperture, or Photoshop CS5. And there are many preset/filters/actions freely available for these programs that cross-process photos.

You can try downloading free cross processing actions for Photoshop. Some may not work with Photoshop Elements 9, but I bet you can find some that will. Try looking here: http://graphic-identity.blogspot.com/2010/03/20-lomo-cross-processing-photoshop.html

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Gimp](http://www.google.pt/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gimp.org%2F&ei=Io9iTY3OB8Wy8QPYt5nxCA&usg=AFQjCNHSDGuHdZTSGB1PiMFTSSn1zSDRCw&sig2=Fbt5H7E22fNY1G7hyIzx3g) - it's free software, but not a webapp.

It doesn't have the great adobe usability experience, but if you know the specific adjustments you want to make, you can make it work for you.

You could also try paint.net, but i don't know if it has the degree of control you need.

Answer (score 2):

[Picnik.com](http://www.picnik.com/) has a couple color related effect you can apply, including "Duo-Tone" and "Cross Process". It's free to use, but some of the other effects require paying for access.

Answer (score 2):

[Picasa](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CGwQFjAB&url=http://picasa.google.com/&ei=j6S8T-qvK4nQsga2k9XBDQ&usg=AFQjCNHHrKCEwrKaKrze1K3hvtv5sDtBsw&sig2=qC13kl9zz9p0b4bSAuPG2Q) allows to apply a cross-process filter to picture, as well as other *[lo-fi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lo-fi_photography)* style filters.

It's not a very configurable filter though, and you can just regulate the intensity, while the tone is preset. The output is pleasant, IMHO.

EDIT: Now I realize that you were looking for online tools :) this is not online, but it's free and it does the job, together with other nice things

Answer (score 2):

Daniel Box had developed a bunch of instagram-like filters implemented as photoshop actions. They are free and pretty good. You may give it a try

http://dbox.tumblr.com/post/5426249009/instagram-filters-as-photoshop-actions

Answer (score 2):

[Fotor](http://www.fotor.com) has many vintage effects. It's a online photos editor,simple but really powerful. I have been using it for a period and I think it's handy and effective.

You can have a try.:)

Answer (score 2):

I interpret "free online" as "can be downloaded for free online". Image View Plus More 2.7 can do it. It has the "curves" like photoshop that you can change as vectors (insert points and drag them to change) and you can change 9 different things with those curves. To change one and then another you click "Incorporate" between each transformation.

In the example below I adjusted "Luminance" to reduce dynamic range for that washed out look, then red, blue and green individually, and finally a vignet. I used to have a "Yellow" setting as well, maybe I should put it back. I'm working on version 3 which is fully 16bit Image processing and 64bit O/S.

[image: Cross processing in image view plus more]
[image: Curves]

Answer (score 0):

Try [PicMonkey](http://www.picmonkey.com).

It has a nice selection of tools and effects.